# Running unittest discover ignoring specific directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unittest

I'm looking for a way of running `python -m unittest discover`, which will discover tests in, say, directories A, B and C. However, directories A, B and C have directories named `dependencies` inside each of them, in which there are also some tests which, however, I don't want to run.

Is there a way to run my tests satisfying these constraints without having to create a script for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and was eventually able to find these handy arguments to pass to unittest discover that resolved my issue.

It is documented here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#test-discovery

```
-s, --start-directory directory
Directory to start discovery (. default)

-p, --pattern pattern
Pattern to match test files (test*.py default)
```

So I modified my command to be:

```
python -m unittest discover -s test
```

since all of the tests I actually want to run are in the one module, test. You could also use the -p to in theory match regex that only hits your tests, ignoring all of the rest it may find.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to do it this way (In *NIX):

```sh
find `pwd` -name '*_test.py' -not -path '*unwanted_path*' \
  | xargs python3 -m unittest -v
```

That is, the tests are discovered by `find`, which allows for options like path pattern exclusions, then they're passed to the `unittest` command as argument list.

Note that I had to switch to `find pwd`, where usually I can write `find .`, since relative paths in the form `./xxx` aren't accepted by `unittest` (module not found).

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that `python -m unittest` descends into module directories but not in other directories.

It quickly tried the following structure

```
temp
  + a
  - test_1.py
  + dependencies
    - test_a.py
```

With the result

```
>python -m unittest discover -s temp\a
test_1
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

OK
```

However, if the directory is a module directory (containing a file `__init__.py`) the situation is different.

```
temp
+ a
  - __init__.py
  - test_1.py
  + dependencies
    - __init__.py
    - test_a.py
```

Here the result was

```
>python -m unittest discover -s temp\a
test_a
.test_1
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.009s

OK
```

The usefulness of this answer for you now depends on whether it is acceptable for your folder `dependencies` not to be a module directory.

EDIT: After seeing your comment

Would using `pytest` be an option? This test runner has many command arguments, one specifically to exclude tests.

See [Changing standard (Python) test discovery](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html)

From their site

> Ignore paths during test collection
>
> You can easily ignore certain test directories and modules during collection by passing the `--ignore=path` option on the cli. pytest allows multiple `--ignore`  options

Comment: Sadly, it does have an `__init__.py` file and it can't be any different :(