# Exclude a subdirectory from unittest discover

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

I'm looking for a way of running `python -m unittest discover -p '*_test.py' -s test`, which will discover tests in **test directory**. However, test directory has many subdirectories. I wanted to exclude a subdirectory, say, **subtest** (name of the subdirectory). There are some options to exclude them in test result after running unittest but I dont want to run the tests on them.
Also is there any options to not use userdefined functions??

Is there a way to run my tests satisfying these constraints without having to create a script for this?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39358442/735926) answer your question?

Comment: @bfontaine Thank you!! I already saw that answer but was getting some errors. So I raised another question. I resolved those errors and is working fine now. :)